# How to recreate this type of gradient in the iOS 9 music logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I was wondering if anyone knew or could point to a tutorial of how to create this type of gradient.

How is it done with three colors and with such a smooth transition between the colors without banding?

[image]

Comment: I see four colors.....

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. What have you tried? Showing some effort here will give your question better chances of receiving a good answer. If you want to know more about the site check the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4):

Draw a bunch of gradients from color to transparent and stack them on top of each other. I used 5 main colors to replicate it.

On the left side from bottom to top a dark blue, a magenta, and a red. Then on the right side from top to bottom orange and light blue:

[image]

Comment: Rats, you posted while I was working on my (nearly identical) answer. Here is my result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwivz.jpg

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I'm quick like a sloth